# "Sign in to facebook" button not showing on iPhone, showing on iPad

Tags: facebook, webview, foursquare, appcelerator-mobile

I am creating an application using Appcelerator. In my app I'll ask for users to log in with Foursquare.

I am accessing Foursquare's login page using a webView and accesing the following URL:

```
https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI
```

However, I am noticing a different behavior in iPhones and iPads.

Here's the login screen on the iPhone:

[image]

And here's the login screen on the iPad:

[image]

So, my question is: Is there any way to show the "Sign in to Facebook" button on the iPhone as well?

Thanks in advance,

Jay Santos

Answer (score 0):

You can make it consistently *not* show the facebook option by adding display=touch to the querystring but other display seem to be ignored rather than letting you override the mobile browser detection.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like something four square is doing. I no I've sent httpClient requests before and your able to modify the user agent string. Perhaps not showing as iPhone would show the button but then it most likely wouldn't look right on the phone.

titanium has built in support to add a facebook login button. Not entirely sure how oauth works but could you add this button (say as a right nav button when on iphone) and then if users login that way would the oauth token get saved correctly for foursquare to it the user is logged in ??